# Bootstrap popover not working properly with class selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble finding out what the best way to write this piece of js code.
Basically i have small boxes displaying a bootstrap popover when each one is clicked.
This is what i got so far:

```
$j('.switcher-field label.switcher-label:not(".no-stock")').each(function(){
            $this = $j(this);
            var text = $j('#size_txt').text();
            $this.popover({
            placement: 'top',
            delay: 200,
            trigger: 'manual',
            html: true,
                content: function () {
                    var $data = $j('span', this);
                    return ''
                        +'<span class="alert-icon"></span>'
                        +'<span style="font-size:13px; font-weight:regular;margin: 0 0 0 35px; display: flex;">'+text+'</span>'+'<div class="pull-right" id="calce-pop" style="text-decoration: underline; margin-bottom: 15px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="scroll();">Ver detalles</div>';
              }}).click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log($this);
                        $j(this).popover('show');
                  });
});
```

The things is that the console.log is always showing me the first element i selected on every click.
Is there a better way to write it so that i can only show the popoup for the select div on each click hiding others popovers?

Comment: try removing the `""` from `.not(".no-stock")`

Comment: Also, why are you doing `$j` instead of just `$` or `jQuery`? That may be your issue. EDIT: nevermind, just read up on it.